# In pandas, set_index is not creating a hierarchical index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

I have a data frame that I am trying to hierarchically index by two columns, State and RegionName. However, whenever I try to set the index, I get, for lack of a better word, parallel indexing and not hierarchical.  I tried the same code for a different data, set and I did not run into this issue.

```
df = pd.read_csv('City_Zhvi_AllHomes.csv') 
df.set_index(["State","RegionName"], inplace = True)
```

The results look like this:
[image]

I have looked around Stackoverflow, but have been unable to find an answer for this,  or even find a similar question.  Any and all help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It is a multiindex. It just doesn't look like it. So try `df.sort_index()` and see what its output looks like - you'll come to understand.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much! I feel silly, but at least I learned something. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Just Perform a `sort_index()` operation on dataframe.

```
df.set_index(["State","RegionName"], inplace = True).sort_index()
```